# is it possible implement php session handler with arangodb

Tags: php, session, arangodb

I 'v posted my question some days ago in the official arangodb website , but no lucks no people answer it .  so i come to here .  below is my question:

just want to know if use arangoDb as a php sessionHandler , how can i delete the session data that expired !

if use the mogodb or mysql to store the session data, we can use such statement to remove the expired data: db.session.remove( { expire: { $gt :} } )
or the sql : delete from tbl_session where expire<:expire

I just want to know how this can be implemented in arangodb . :)

Comment: Where did you originally post the question? Can you send us a link, so we can find out why we did not get a notification. The official forum is at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/arangodb the issue tracker at https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/issues?state=open

Comment: may be i posted in a wrong place (it will be better there have an irc channel for discussing arangoDb , do you have any plan this?) : https://www.arangodb.org/2013/03/15/getting-started-with-arangodb-and-symfony-part4#comment-1252752390

Answer (score 3):

We do not yet support modifying AQLs.
So you need to execute a bit of code:

```
var q = db._query("FOR s in session filter s.expire < 1393231738788 return s");
while (q.hasNext()) {
  db.session.remove(q.next());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

mchacki's answer is correct till ArangoDB 2.2.

Since 2.2 we do have modified queries so the new query for our Database would look like this:

```
FOR s IN sessions
  FILTER s.expire < DATE_NOW()-86400000
  REMOVE s IN sessions
```

With this example one day old sessions would be deleted.